# How find the domain of an integral function

Tags: integration, functions, solution-verification

I want to fully understand the idea to find the domain of an integral function.

I have understood that if I have a function as
$$F(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt$$
to find the domain I have to find:
a) the domain of $f(t)$
b) observe if the function has a convergent improper integral in the point excluded from the domain of $f$.
c)take the domain of $f$ (eventually extended with the point b)) which contain $x_0$.
**Example:**
$$F(x)=\int_{2}^{x}1-\frac{sin^2t}{t}dt$$
I can say that the integrated function is defined when $t\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. Now I see that the point $0$ is excluded from the domain BUT, since $1-\frac{sin^2t}{t}\sim 1-t,$ as $t\to0$ then I can say that the function in $x=0$ is integrable. 
Moreover $2\in (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, so I can conclude that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (considering the addition of 0 from the consideration of the convergent improper integral).

On the other hand if $x_0$ is not in the domain of $f$, firstly I have to check if in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ the function is integrable, otherwise, the integral function does not exist.
**Example:**
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}dt$$
I see that $f$ is defined in $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$. So the lower extreme of integral does not belong in the domain of $f$, BUT the function is integrable in a neighbourhood of $0$, so I conclude that $F(x)\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Am I right in all my ideas?**

Comment: While I won't deny that [tag:integral-domain] sounds perfect for your question, I assure you that it isn't. :-)

Comment: ...I think I have not understood what you mean, sorry!

Comment: No worries, I just removed a tag.

Comment: Ah ok very thanks!

Comment: the question doesn't make any sense, as a function, by definition, have a predefined domain. Maybe you want to search the greater subset of the real line where the algebraic expression $\int_{x_0}^x f(t)\,d t$ is well-defined for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry but I have not understood your comment...if I want to study the integral function I want to determine the domain...

Comment: Does this help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral ?

Comment: @user600016 I know what is an improper integral, I would like to know only if my proceedement is correct!